# How to conditionally update and import nodes using Migrate?

Tags: migrations

I need to migrate new nodes and update others in the same time. 2 installations of the same project are out of sync, which means, that the same `nid` may not indicate the same node on both sides. But I'm sure they're the same if their titles are equal. So I think, that I need a conditional field mapping, as illustrated in the following pseudocode:

```
if source_nid = destination_nid
  if source_title = destination_title
    addFieldMapping('nid', 'nid')
else 
  continue
```

I have only one idea, how can I do this - split migrations into two different parts with filters managed by `prepareRow()` method (one of the for node updating, the other for import of new nodes). Is this the only way? I would appreciate something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

OK, at least now I know, that splitting migration into two with filtered rows works just fine. `prepareRow` function looks like this:

```
public function prepareRow($row) {
  // If node exists on destination
  if ($node = node_load($row->nid)) {
    // Use the metatdata wrapper to pull values
    $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    // If destination title is the same as source title
    if ($node_wrapper->label() == $row->title) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```